# Getting error "PropTypes is not defined" in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, react-proptypes

Well, this code throws an error in console - "PropTypes is not defined", so application does not render. Any ideas what's wrong in configuration or even code? I am not using eslint if it matters btw.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class Movie extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    movie: Proptypes.shape({
      title: Proptypes.string.isRequired
    })
  };
  static defaultProps = {
    description: 'Description is not available'
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{this.props.movie.title}</h3>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

However this works as expected(after component):

```
Movie.propTypes = {
  movie: PropTypes.shape({
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  })
}
```

package.json configuration:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "live-server": "^1.2.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "webpack": "^4.3.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13"
  }
}
```

.babelrc configuration:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill','./src/app.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'env', 'stage-3', 'stage-2', 'stage-1', 'stage-0']
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.s?css$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'sass-loader'
      ]
    }]
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

Comment: There is a typo in `static propTypes = {
    movie: Proptypes.shape({
      title: Proptypes.string.isRequired
    })
  };`, `PropTypes` is written as `Proptypes`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo here:-

```
static propTypes = {
    movie: Proptypes.shape({
      title: Proptypes.string.isRequired
    })
  };
```

It should be:-

```
static propTypes = {
    movie: PropTypes.shape({
      title: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    })
  };
```